# Downloading a big file with URLSession downloadTask crashes at end

Tags: ios, swift, networking, urlsession

I need to download a big mp4 file (>2gb) and it crashes on an iPhone mini but not on a new iPhone 15.

The whole download works well and the memory is stable but when it finishes the memory spikes until the app crashes.
I used to do `try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)` since I want to save it in a specific directory but even commenting the line the app runs out of memory. Any idea how to do it?

This and `print("File downloaded successfully!")` the successful completionHandler get called.

```
private func downloadFile(from url: URL, name: String, progressHandler: @escaping (Double) -> Void, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { location, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error downloading file:", error)
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let location = location else {
                print("Download location not available.")
                completionHandler(nil, nil)
                return
            }
            
            guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
                print("Documents directory not found.")
                return
            }

            let destinationURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(name).mp4")
            do {
//                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
                print("File downloaded successfully!")
                completionHandler(location, nil)
            } catch {
                print("Error moving downloaded file:", error)
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
        
        let downloadProgress = task.progress
        let progressQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.progressQueue", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)
        
        let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 100)
        progress.completedUnitCount = 0
        
        let progressTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
            progressQueue.async {
                progress.completedUnitCount = Int64(downloadProgress.fractionCompleted * 100)
                progressHandler(progress.fractionCompleted)
            }
            
            if progress.isFinished {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense since downloadTask writes it to disk. You must be trying to load the resulting file to memory somewhere in your code

Comment: @LeoDabus yep that's what I thought as well but I triple checked and actually I just made it call without doing anything with the result... So I'm pretty lost here

Comment: What happens when `completion(location, nil)` is called?

Comment: Not related to your question but you can simply use a `UIProgressView` and set the `task.progress` to the `observedProgress` property. This way you can get rid of the timer.

Comment: Side note: `completionHandler(location, nil)` should be `completionHandler(destinationURL, nil)`, as `location` should be invalid at the closure end. How does it crashes? Is there an error in console? If it crashes only while using Xcode, try without Xcode, as the debugger is taking some resources from the devices. You can have heavy code working on new devices with debugger failing with old devices with debugger, but not without it (but it's getting to its limit).